# r geom_errorbar and geom_ribbon with inverted colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataset.

```
Color    y       y_min    y_max     x
After   -4.107   -4.986   -3.229    2018
After   -3.395   -4.015   -2.775    2017
After   -2.955   -3.292   -2.618    2016
After   -2.082   -2.406   -1.758    2015
After   -0.993   -1.328   -0.659    2014
Before   0        0        0        2013
Before   0.211   -0.148    0.569    2012
Before   0.125   -0.276    0.526    2011
Before   0.056   -0.565    0.677    2010
Before   0.642    0.0100   1.273    2009
Before   0.429   -0.241    1.099    2008
```

My goal is to generate

1. error bars for each x
2. Overlay a `geom_ribbon` and
3. color the error bar and `geom_ribbon` differently for x (Before, 2013) and x (After , 2013).
   all values (Before, 2013) to be in blue and all values (After , 2013) to be shaded in red.

[image]

I have tried this

```
df %>%
ggplot(aes(x=x, y = y, color= Color) +
  geom_line() +
    geom_point(size =2) +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y_min, ymax = y_max)) + 
       geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, y = y, ymax = y_max, ymin = y_min, fill = Color), alpha = 0.2) + 
         scale_colour_manual(value = c(Before = "blue", After = "red"))
```

This is not working, any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for both colored ribbons to touch the "singularity" at 2013, you need to add a duplicate "After" row at 2013. To get the colors to switch, you can just assign different colors to the fill and color scales. To have the ribbon outlined in the correct color, we can use `after_scale` on its color:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(x == 2013) %>% mutate(Color = "After")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, ymin = y_min, ymax = y_max, color = Color)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(fill = Color, color = after_scale(scales::alpha(fill, 1))),
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("blue3", "red3")) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("red3", "blue3")) +
  scale_x_continuous("Year", breaks = 2008:2018) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]